# PHP include works but JQuery load doesn't

Tags: php, jquery, load

I have a bit of code in a div which needs to be refreshed every few seconds.
If I use a PHP include, the page works fine, but obviously can't be refreshed.
When I use a jquery load, none of my PHP functions work within the included file and none of the php variables are recognised. Any help would be hugely appreciated!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function refreshPosts() {

    $('div#refresh').load('/include/included_file.php');
    setTimeout("refreshPosts()",1000);

} 
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    refreshPosts();
});
</script>
```

In my php file, there are calls to various functions, which result in this:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function myFunction()

Comment: please provide ur __code__ on here..

Comment: Any code/error message/... would be hugely appreciated in order to help you...

Comment: change this line `setTimeout("refreshPosts()",1000);` to `setTimeout(function(){refreshPosts();},1000);`

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not add any code or helpful errors, we can only speculate on problem. My guess is the problem is the following:

Your main page has in it's php code some includes, or some object instantiations, which does not exist on your "jquery loaded" (I guess you mean an ajax request by that) page. I'm about 90% sure this is your problem, but can't give more details since... well... lack of things to go on.